# Did echo change in Powershell with Set-ExecutionPolicy recently?

Tags: powershell

Did something change in powershell regarding the ECHO pipe? I have been using it for a long while. I get an input error that its complaining about format..... Curious if something change in since the 5.1 release..

```
echo Y | Set-Executionpolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: The only piped-through input parameters for `Set-ExecutionPolicy` are `-ExecutionPolicy` and `-Scope`. Neither takes `'Y'` as valid input, so do what [RetiredGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70906519/9898643) says in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aarin,

Do it the PowerShell way:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Comment: I must have had a brain fart on this. I feel dumb now haha its all coming back. Thanks!